# loading json from text file

Tags: python, json

I am trying to run this code but it creates error.

```
import json
import requests
import pprint
data = []
with open('data.txt') as o1:
  for line in o1:
    data.append(json.loads(line))
    print(data)
    print(" \n")
print(data)
url = 'http://xyz.abcdfx.in/devicedata'
body_json=json.dumps(data)
headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
d = requests.post(url, data = body_json, headers=headers)
pprint.pprint(d.json())
```

it shows

> ```
> Value Error: No json object could be Decoded
> ```

I am new to programming and not able to figure out what is the problem.

Comment: Does it throw that error _only_ when started from your crontab?

Comment: no it throws this error whenever i run this script

Comment: i'm sorry i think the title of this question is not right

Comment: At boot time? Maybe networking isn't up yet?

Comment: Btw, show us output of this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem using this:

```
data =[]
with open('data.txt') as f:
   for line in f:
      data = json.loads(line)
      print(data)
      url = 'http://xyz.abcdfx.cn/devicedata'
      body_json=json.dumps(data)
      headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
      d = requests.post(url, data = body_json, headers=headers)
      pprint.pprint(d.json())
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to parse the json file line by line, but the json objects may (and usually are) span more than one line. You need to have the **entire** file in order to parse it:

```
 with open('data.txt') as o1:
      data = json.loads(o1.read()) # read ALL the file and parse. no loops
 print(data)
```

Comment: i tried this code but it again throw a Error :Value Error: Extra Data:

Comment: @Aaron.0 can you open `'data.txt'` in any external json reader? It seems like the file is "not purely" json(?)

Comment: its json alright it runs well when there is only single data in 'data.txt' but throws error when there are more than that

Comment: @Aaron.0 who writes `data.txt`? why are there several "json data" in there?